# Use AWS Identity Center with okta-aws-cli

Tags: okta, aws-iam-identity-center

We have recently upgraded to Okta Identity Engine, which is integrated with AWS Identity Center. We needed to know if there is any way to integrate AWS IDC with okta-aws-cli. https://github.com/okta/okta-aws-cli

The above cli requires integration only with AWS Federated App, to provide an allowed web sso client ID. https://help.okta.com/oie/en-us/content/topics/deploymentguides/aws/aws-configure-cli.htm
However, the same option is not available for AWS Identity Center. Please let me know if there is any alternative way to configure it.